# In Clojure, how to use a java Class dynamically?

Tags: clojure

In Clojure, how to use a java Class that is stored in a variable?

How should I fix the following code?

```
(def a java.lang.String)
(new a "1"); CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve classname: a
```

And why this one works fine?

```
(def a str)
(a "1")
```

Comment: I thought this has come up before and indeed it has: see [Clojure: creating new instance from String class name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3748559/232707) with a great answer by Chouser which mentions both `clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeConstructor` and another approach, a sort of middle ground between "static+fast" and "dynamic+slow" (you could call it "very dynamic+slow once, static+fast later"), which may well be of interest to you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most elegant solution is to write `construct` that does the same as `new` but is able to receive a class dynamically:

```
 (defn construct [klass & args]
    (clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeConstructor klass (into-array Object args)))
 (def a HashSet)
 (construct a '(1 2 3)); It works!!!
```

This solution overcomes the limitation of [@mikera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214010/mikera)'s answer (see comments).

Special Thanks to [@Michał Marczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/232707/michal-marczyk) that made me aware of `invokeConstructor` answering another question of mine: [Clojure: how to create a record inside a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9308138/813665).

Another option is to store the call to the constructor as an anonymous function. In our case:

```
(def a #(String. %1))
(a "111"); "111"
```

Answer (score 7):

When you define a in this way, you get a var containing a java.lang.Class

```
(def a java.lang.String)

(type a)
=> java.lang.Class
```

You then have 2 options:

A: Construct the new instance dynamically by finding the Java constructor using the reflection API. Note that as Yehonathan points out you need to use the *exact* class defined in the constructor signature (a subclass won't work as it won't find the correct signature):

```
(defn construct [klass & args]
  (.newInstance
    (.getConstructor klass (into-array java.lang.Class (map type args)))
    (object-array args)))

(construct a "Foobar!")
=> "Foobar!"
```

B: Construct using Clojure's Java interop, which will require an eval:

```
(defn new-class [klass & args]
  (eval `(new ~klass ~@args)))

(new-class a "Hello!")
=> "Hello!"
```

Note that method A is considerably faster (about 60x faster on my machine), I think mainly because it avoids the overhead of invoking the Clojure compiler for each eval statement.

Comment: There is an issue with `construct` when passing as argument a derived class of the class defined in the signature. For instance `(construct HashSet '(8))` causes an exception while `(new HashSet '(8))` doesn't.

Comment: Option B: looks fine. Are there any limitations/concerns due to the usage of `eval`?

Comment: Potential downsides of eval: Watch out for externally-provided values - there could be a code injection security risk. Also eval has some additional overhead as it invokes the Clojure compiler. It can also lead to some "clever" code that is tricky to maintain if you are not careful. In general eval is fine if used with caution.

Comment: Have a look at my answer below: it overcomes the limitation of Option B.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that Clojure implements Java interop using a number of special forms:

```
user=> (doc new)
-------------------------
new
Special Form
  Please see http://clojure.org/special_forms#new
nil
```

this basically means the "normal" Clojure syntax is altered to allow for handier constructs when calling Java. As a naive reflection solution to your dynamic Java needs, you can leverage [`eval`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/eval):

```
user=> (def a String) ; java.lang package is implicitly imported
#'user/a
user=> `(new ~a "test") ; syntax quote to create the correct form
(new java.lang.String "test")
user=> (eval `(new ~a "test")) ; eval to execute
"test"
```

The same strategy works with all the other interop special forms, like [method invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6631165/350923).

---

EDIT: look also at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9186889/350923) from [@mikera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214010/mikera) for a more performing alternative via the Java reflection API.