# Clojure: how to create a record inside a function?

Tags: clojure

In clojure, I would like to create a record inside a function.

I tried:

```
(defn foo []
  (defrecord MyRecord [a b])
  (let [b (MyRecord. "1" "2")]))
```

But it causes an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve classname: MyRecord
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### The key points

You should only use `defrecord` at top level.<sup>1</sup>

So, if you do need a custom record type, you should define it outside of `foo` (at some point in your code which gets processed before `foo`'s definition).

Otherwise, you could just use a regular map. In particular, if `foo` will be creating entities of multiple "types" (at the conceptual level), it probably makes no sense to try to create a record type (a Java class) for each; the natural solution would be to use maps holding a `:type` key to indicate the sort of entity represented.

#### Why it doesn't work

The code from the question doesn't compile, because Clojure's compiler resolves class names mentioned as first arguments to `new` forms at compile time. (`(MyRecord. "1" "2")` is expanded to `(new MyRecord "1" "2")` during the macro expansion process.) Here the name `MyRecord` cannot yet be resolved to the appropriate class, because the latter has not yet been defined (it would be created by the `defrecord` form after `foo` was first called).

To get around this, you could do something horrible like

```
(defn foo []
  (eval '(defrecord MyRecord [x y]))
  (let [b (clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeConstructor
           ;; assuming MyRecord will get created in the user ns:
           (Class/forName "user.MyRecord")
           (into-array Object ["1" "2"]))]
    b))
```

which causes a kitten to have its `finalize` method invoked through reflection, resulting in a gruesome death.

As a final remark, the above horrible version would sort of work, but it would also create a new record type under the same name at each invocation. This causes weirdness to ensue. Try the following examples for a flavour:

```
(defprotocol PFoo (-foo [this]))

(defrecord Foo [x]
  PFoo
  (-foo [this] :foo))

(def f1 (Foo. 1))

(defrecord Foo [x])

(extend-protocol PFoo
  Foo
  (-foo [this] :bar))

(def f2 (Foo. 2))

(defrecord Foo [x])

(def f3 (Foo. 3))

(-foo f1)
; => :foo
(-foo f2)
; => :bar
(-foo f3)
; breaks

;; and of course
(identical? (class f1) (class f2))
; => false
(instance? (class f1) f2)
; => false
```

At this point, `(Class/forName "user.Foo")` (assuming again that all this happens in the `user` namespace) returns the class of `f3`, of which neither `f1` nor `f2` is an instance.

---

<sup>1</sup> Macros occasionally might output a `defrecord` form wrapped in a `do` along with some other forms; top-level `do`s are special, though, in that they act as if the forms they wrap were individually processed at top level.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The `invokeConstructor` function that you refer to helped me solve a very challenging riddle: see my 2nd answer of  http://stackoverflow.com/q/9167457/813665

Comment: Why does the `defrecord` part inside `foo` have to be executed through `eval`?

Comment: Happy to help. I'd have posted the `Reflector` bit over there earlier had I noticed that question in an SO answering moment -- glad this came up here. About the `foo` above, I used `eval` during an experiment to be able to determine the name of the created record dynamically, then simplified it to this version -- I suppose I could have taken out `eval` then. Once the shape of the `defrecord` form is statically fixed, `eval` is indeed unnecessary, although in that case there is also *no reason whatsoever* not to use a top-level `defrecord` to gain a sporting chance at producing a sane program.

Comment: Using `defrecord` within a function is pretty much guaranteed to be at least one of "providing no benefit to the surrounding code" and "causing weird and subtle breakage", and most likely both; the only reason to play with it that I can see is to learn about Clojure's implementation details. Otherwise it's just gallows-grade rope... Mostly writing this so that nobody, by any stretch of the imagination, can get the impression that I offered the `foo` above as a model for production code -- I only posted it for completeness and because I think it's fun to abuse Clojure at the REPL sometimes.

Comment: Do you know the reason why Clojure's compiler resolves class names mentioned as first arguments to new forms at compile time? Why does this need to be at **compile** time?

Comment: Because postponing this to runtime would be dreadfully inefficient. Reflection is *slow*. The current situation is simple: you pay for what you use. If you know the name of your class beforehand, which is the case in the vast majority of cases, you get to construct your objects with simple syntax at full speed of the host. If your use case is special and you need to be more dynamic, you can, to various degrees (that is, there are several solutions you can choose from), at the cost of speed and the code being somewhat cumbersome to write.