# Invoke method of a class which name is generated dynamically

Tags: java, clojure

I'm writting simple application in Clojure. My task is to get (from user) fully qualified class name (Java class) which implements Runnable interface and invoke start method. My problem is how run this method when i don't know class name a-priori? Based on [this](http://clojure.org/java_interop) i've tried something like this (on simple String class) but i failed:

```
(defn schedule [parameter]
  (def class-name (subs parameter 6))       ; get just class name for e.g. java.lang.String
  (println (.getName class-name)))
```

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167457/in-clojure-how-to-use-a-java-class-dynamically) but i'm not quite sure how to use it, because i failed with it also. Any ideas?

Comment: could you add some sample intput and desired output for schedule?

Comment: It's just an example of what i need. Finally i will invoke one of my own classes, which implement Java.lang.Runnable, so i will need to invoke myClass.start() and just leave it. So output is NULL and input is as i wrote fully qualified class name (class name with package name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to avoid using macros, you could do something like:

```
(defn schedule [name]
  (let [thread (-> name Class/forName .newInstance Thread.)]
    (.start thread)
    thread))
```

You could then interact with the returned Thread object in the usual Java ways.

Comment: Don't bother this subs. One question about your solution. How am i able to check if thread started?

Comment: Sorry, left out the crucial `(Thread.)` step! I've refactored the snippet above to return the thread itself so you could interact with if if so desired.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll check that tomorrow, cause today i'm like zombie :D

Comment: Okey, i think that it works but i have problem - where do i have to place my java class to be visible in this Clojure application?

Comment: Anywhere such that it's on your classpath. If you're using leiningen, you can run `lein classpath` to see what that includes and put it in one of those places, or you could install it to your local Maven repo and include it as a project dependency to have it automatically available.

Comment: I use IntelliJ with La Clojure plugin

Comment: Then you should be able to open up your project settings under the 'Libraries' section and add an entry to point to whatever directory you choose to drop your compiled Java classes into.

Comment: yeah but what if classname is known only at runtime? then i`m not able to add library cause application already run

Comment: The JVM just needs to know where (e.g. under what directory) to look for the `.class` files. You don't need to know the class's name for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a macro or `eval`. In general prefer a macro to eval.

```
user> (defmacro runnerizer [class-name] 
          `(~(symbol (str class-name "/" "start"))))                                                    
#'user/runnerizer                                                                                                                     
user> (macroexpand-1 '(runnerizer "myClass"))                                                                                         
(myClass/start)
```

Comment: Ohh great. And how can i check if thread have already started? And more over, where i have to place my class to be visible for my Clojure application?

Comment: I think you might have to use eval to get it working with a classname passed in at runtime - or is there another way to defer macroexpansion until after compilation?

Comment: the Class/forName approach should work at runtime as well as eval. Given that I'm going to vote for dfreeman's answer because I'm biased against using eval