# Apply for Java constructors

Tags: java, clojure

I have a vector of values, say `[210 50 60]` and I need to create Java object with it. For example I want to create `Color`:

```lisp
(Color. 210 50 60)         ; standard way
(apply Color. [210 50 60]) ; hmm... I need something like this
```

Of course `Color.` is not a function and we cannot use `apply` on it. Is there an elegant way to solve this task or do I have to write it like this:

```
(let [[r g b] [210 50 60]]
  (Color. r g b))
```

Comment: what about having a constructor with 3 ints as parameters?

Comment: I think the closest thing is making a lambda wrapper: `(apply #(Color. %1 %2 %3) ...)`

Comment: @Marco, well it isn't better then `let` solution. It is clear that such wrapping is just a way to somehow use `apply` in context where it is useless a priori. Proper solution to the problem would be some kind of standard macro, I think.

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/a/9172515/151650 good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont mind paying the reflection cost I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/9172515/151650 is an elegant way.
If you don't mind crazy macros:

```clj
(defn arity [c i]
  (let [args (map #(symbol (str "arg" %)) (range i))]
    `([~@args] (new ~c ~@args))))

(defmacro ->c [c]
   (let [cs (.getConstructors (resolve c))
         arities (set (map #(count (.getParameterTypes %)) cs))
         fn-arities (map #(arity c %) arities)]
     `(fn ~@fn-arities)))

(apply (->c java.awt.Color) 1 [2 3])
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think it is possible... Although now I prefer simple solution with `let`.